# Changing servlet context path in JHipster, automatically logins as anonymous user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

Currently JHipster creates Controllers with `/api` path on every controller. I want to make this path as `/xyz/api` (common) for every controller, so I removed `/api` from each controller and added `servletContext` in application.yml. Below is the code for it:

```
server:
servlet:
    session:
        cookie:
            http-only: true
    contextPath: /xyz/api
```

I also changed security configurations as belows:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(this.corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.problemSupport).accessDeniedHandler(this.problemSupport).and().csrf()
            .disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/register").permitAll().antMatchers("/xyz/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll().antMatchers("/xyz/api/**")
            .authenticated().antMatchers("/xyz/api/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/management/info").permitAll().antMatchers("/xyz/api/management/**")
            .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN).antMatchers("/xyz/api/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xyz/api/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .and()
            .apply(this.securityConfigurerAdapter());

}
```

Now when I run this application, it automatically logins as an anonymous user. I marked that `/account` service is being called on application load, and it is fetching details of anonymous user. Before these changes `/account` was showing `401 not authorized` error.

What am I missing here? Why it is login as an anonymous user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SecurityConfiguration must not include the context-path in the path matchers.

I wouldn't recommend the changes you are making, I would advise setting a context-path without `/api` in it.  With the way you are doing it, the user interface will be served under `/api` as well (which will probably make securing `/**` not work as expected).

You will also have to  these changes every time you upgrade JHipster.

Comment: I already have removed `/api` from each resource (same thing is pointed by the user who has asked this question)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: agreed with you UI point. But that still doesn't solve my problem. Why am I automatically getting logged in as an anonymous user after changing context path? Am I missing some changes which need to be done for security after changing context path?

Comment: See the first sentence of the answer.  You aren't securing `/account` which then lets an anonymousUser receive a result instead of a 401

Comment: Isn't securing `/xyz/api/**` secures `/xyz/api/account`?

Comment: You are ignoring the first sentence of this answer.  You don't include the context-path in the matcher, you should be securing `/account` not `/xyz/api/account`.  You can enable spring security debug logs and you will see that it doesn't include the context-path when matching paths

Comment: Aha. Gotcha! Silly mistake. I thought servlet context can be considered in matchers, but actually spring security secures every path which is written in matchers after appending it to context path. Thanks man!